# Expand into power series $f(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$

Tags: logarithms, power-series

As in the topic, I am also supposed to find the radius of convergence. 
My solution: $$\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})=\log \left ( x(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})\right )=\log(x)+\log(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})$$Now I tried to use expansion for $\log(1+x)$ as $x\rightarrow0:\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$$
\log(1+(x-1))=(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}-\cdots=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(x-1)^k $$ $$\log(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})= \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}-\frac{(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})^2}{2}+\frac{(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})^3}{3}-\cdots=$$$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})^k$$Here I end up with nasty identity $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(x-1)^k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1})^k$$and I don't know how to evaluate it into one serie. ($|x|<1$). Any hints? Thanks in advance

Comment: Call $u:=\sqrt{1+1/x^2}$. Then you can get a radius of converges in terms of $u$ and then just intersect that with the range of the squareroot and the series for $\log(x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Radius of convergence for the $\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$ will be the same as for $(1+x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$

Comment: heh, that's pretty neat. (+1) great hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier to do if you instead consider the power series expansion of $\log(1-x)$.$$\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$
We then manipulate this to yield $(\log(1-x))^2=\log(1-x)\log(1-x)$, so:$$(\log(1-x))^2=\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\right)$$Have you ever toyed with multiplication of polynomials? Intuitively so, multiplying such power series is virtually identical. The coefficients of our product is the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the coefficients of our individual series.$$\begin{align*}(\log(1-x))^2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k(n-k)}\right)x^n\\&=\dots\end{align*}$$

Comment: I am sorry, there was error in original message, I wrote wrong f for that quest- not it is correct

Comment: @fdhd: oh, apologies for that!

Answer (score 0):

Your function, as a function on the complex numbers, is analytic at most points, and has branch points at

$$ z^2 + 1 = 0$$

due to the square root, and at

$$ z + \sqrt{z^2+1} = 0 $$

due to the logarithm.

The points satisfying the first equation are $\pm i$, and there are no solutions to the second equation.

(minor technical point: check that $\pm i$ truly are branch points, rather than simply being the only possibilities for branch points)

So the only singularities of your function are at $z=i$ and $z=-i$. The Taylor series for $f(z)$ around any point $a$, then, will have radius of convergence

$$ \min\{ |a-i|, |a+i| \} $$